# How to use headphone as well as my laptop speaker at the same time. I am having conexant driver not Realtek

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, drivers, speakers

I know there are many questions related to mine in SO but all of them gives only solution to those who are using Realtek sound driver but mine is **conexant** and I am also unable to see headphone in sound playback devices which is basically a solution for many guys and also I am using a Laptop whereas many guys out there are using PC.

I have also tried contacting **Lenovo** who is manufacturer of my laptop they are saying to contact Microsoft and then I have contacted microsoft and they don't have any idea how to do that...

So I thought why not I give a try with you guys.

I am using **Lenovo Ideapad** with **windows 10 OS** and conexant driver.

I can also go with any 3rd party software. In fact I have tried one i.e. (Voicemeter) but that also didn't work.

Hope you guys understand the seriousness of the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that this is disabled at a hardware level, and thus not possible to get around by software.

The easiest and best solution to have audio on both speakers and laptop, is by buying a jack splitter cable (these are really cheap). It will split the audio from one out to two outs. You then connect both the speaker and the headphones to that cable and the system no longer knows that you have 2 devices connected, and such it will work.

It is likely that the volume will go down on both devices, this is unavoidable unless you connect your pc to an amplifier, but that is more expensive. Amplifiers usually do have the ability to play both the speakers and the headphone though.

Comment: Yeah at last I will with this option..because my laptop has Dolby speaker so this is also one of the reason I am trying to use both at same time...If not I will definitely go with your method...Thanks for the reply

Comment: LPChip are you sure that there is no option left for me...?

Comment: I'm quite sure, yes. It is very unlikely that it can be done, it is usually on addon soundcards where this is possible, not on integrated soundcards.

Comment: One thing though, if you are talking about integrated speakers, a splitter cable will not work, because the integrated speakers have no cable to connect.